# R/Python: Converting PDF's To Tables

Tags: python, r, ocr, tesseract, data-manipulation

I have a PDF image file (e.g. "p1.pdf" - this is a scanned copy of the original document) saved on my computer - this file looks something like this (I added the red lines to show the distinctions):

[image]

I would like to import this PDF into R, and convert it into a "table object". I tried to do this by following this [tutorial](https://themockup.blog/posts/2021-01-18-reading-tables-from-images-with-magick/) (+ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html):

```
library(tesseract)
library(magick)
library(png)
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)

pngfile <- pdftools::pdf_convert('p1.pdf', dpi = 600)
text <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile)
cat(text)

raw_img <- image_read(pngfile)

raw_img %>% 
    image_ocr()
```

This seems to have worked - I continued to follow the tutorial:

```
num_only <- tesseract::tesseract(
  options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = c(".0123456789 "))
  )

raw_img %>% 
  image_quantize(colorspace = 'gray') %>% 
  image_threshold() %>% 
  image_crop(geometry_area(100, 0, 600, 40)) %>% 
  ocr(engine = num_only) 

combo <- tesseract::tesseract(
    options = list(
      tessedit_char_whitelist = paste0(
        c(letters, LETTERS, " ", ".0123456789 (-)"), collapse = "")
      ))

raw_text <- raw_img %>%
  image_quantize(colorspace = "gray") %>%
  image_transparent("white", fuzz = 22) %>%
  image_background("white") %>%
  image_threshold() %>%
  image_crop(geometry_area(0, 0, 110, 45)) %>%  
  ocr(engine = combo)
```

Now, I am trying to convert this into a table ("tibble"):

```
raw_tibble <- raw_text %>% 
  str_split(pattern = "\n") %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  tibble(data = .) 

# A tibble: 68 x 1
   data                                        
   <chr>                                       
 1 "- ALPHABETICAL LISTING ABT"                
 2 "a PlaceYear of Reg"                        
 3 "Name Address Graduation Year"              
 4 ""                                          
 5 "- (John Smith) BC ABC Uni~
 6 ""                                          
 7 "Email: jsmith@gmail.com P"999-999-~
 8 "BCC University 2002"                     
 9 "- Jane Smith HGH Univer~
10 "Email janes@gmail.com "    
# ... with 58 more rows
```

The problem is from here - the instructions relating to further tidying the results within the tutorial seem to be very specific to the example in the tutorial (i.e. related to football). As such, I can not apply them to my problem.
Can someone please show me how I can take the results I have and transform them into a table that looks closer to the original PDF?

Maybe someone can try to save the picture I uploaded as a png file and see if they can get this code to work?

Thanks!

**Note 1:**

- As such, I am only interested in the "Name" and "Address" columns
- I am also open to a lot of flexibility in the final format of the table. For example  "`401 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 P: 555-555-5555 501 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 p:666-666-6666 601 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 p:666-666-6666`" can all appear as a single line
- This means that in the final table, everything "entry" between 2 sets of red lines can be represented by 3 columns and 1 row

As a result, the final table can look something like this:

```
  id                                 Name                                                                                                                                                                     Address
1  1  (John Smith) Email:jsmith@gmail.com                                                                                                                                                           AB p:999-999-9999
2  2     Jane Smith Email:janes@gmail.com                                                                                                                                                              p:111-111-1111
3  3                          Henry Smith                                                                                                                    201 Fake St,Some City, Some State A1C B23 P:111-222-3333
4  4                          Jason Smith                                                                                                                     301 Fake St Some City,Some State A1C B23 P:555-555-5555
5  5         Luke Smith lsmith2@gmail.com 401 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 P: 555-555-5555 501 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 p:666-666-6666 601 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 p:666-666-6666
                                         Place_Year_Graduation Reg_Year
1 ABC University 2001, BCC University 2002,DEF University 2003     2000
2                  HGH University/2001, Some Other School 2002     2000
3                                               University ABC     1999
4                                                   Univer 123     2005
5                                                  ABC College     2010

final = structure(list(id = 1:5, Name = c(" (John Smith) Email:jsmith@gmail.com", 
"Jane Smith Email:janes@gmail.com", "Henry Smith", "Jason Smith", 
"Luke Smith lsmith2@gmail.com"), Address = c("AB p:999-999-9999", 
"p:111-111-1111", "201 Fake St,Some City, Some State A1C B23 P:111-222-3333", 
"301 Fake St Some City,Some State A1C B23 P:555-555-5555", "401 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 P: 555-555-5555 501 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 p:666-666-6666 601 Fake St Some City, Some State A1C B23 p:666-666-6666"
), Place_Year_Graduation = c("ABC University 2001, BCC University 2002,DEF University 2003", 
"HGH University/2001, Some Other School 2002", "University ABC", 
"Univer 123", "ABC College"), Reg_Year = c(2000, 2000, 1999, 
2005, 2010)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Note 2:** I understand that this is a difficult problem and that R might not be the best suited tool for this problem - therefore, I am also open to using Python for this problem.

Comment: As a start point, it's worth checking what you get if you try `text <- pdftools::pdf_text('p1.pdf')` - many PDFs store text in tabular format so you can skip the OCR step for possibly higher accuracy reads.

Comment: @ Paul: thank you for your answer! When I tried your code, this is what I got:

Comment: > text <- pdftools::pdf_text('p1.pdf')
> text
[1] ""

Comment: The PDF contains a "scan" of the original document -  I think this is why your code won't run? thank you so much!

Comment: No worries - seems like the OCR route is the right one, just thought it might save you a little trouble!  Will look into how to manipulate what you've got.  Edit - can you add a dput of your `raw_text` object to the main question post?

Comment: Sure - something like this: "- ALPHABETICAL LISTING ABT\nPlace/Year of Reg\nName Address Graduation Year\n-, (John Smith) , AB ABC University/

Comment: It won't work in a comment - I think you need to edit your question to add it to the main post please.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the OCR is working row-wise with no knowledge of the column format or word wrapping, and since the right hand column is vertically centred we can't easily use the "date" as a marker for a true new line.  Having had a look around, it seems like the best way to preserve the columns may be with the tesseract "page segmentation mode" option - I think setting it to "1" should attempt to preserve your columns.

Comment: @ Paul: thank you for your reply!  Maybe you can try saving the picture I uploaded as a png file and see if ocr works? Can you please show me an example of how to use the page segmentation mode? Thanks!

Comment: I've had a play and I'm stumped - the combined challenges (multiline cells, no cell borders) seem to make this very tricky.  I've seen posts suggesting `daiR` could get it working but I can't use that service from where I'm working.  You could create a vector of column edges and a vector of row starts and run the OCR on each individual "cell" but that seems very manual for a large table.  It's likely that the `magicK` package would include something that can detect the column/row edges programmatically but I am not familiar enough to figure it out.  Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Does this need to be done in R or Python? Tabula https://tabula.technology/ was written specifically to deal with this issue, and it does very well, especially on basic tables like yours.

Comment: @ DuckPyjamas : Thank you for your reply! Can you please show me an example as to how I would do this? Thank you!

Comment: @stats_noob It's got a GUI so it's quite approachable. Here's a walkthrough: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEusn9HB1sc

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not R specific, in such cases I would try to run tesseract as best it can from a shell command line via a pdf service (API) that should re-generate and maintain the pdf text layout. Personally I only run a few files at a time because each needs some edits.

In this case its minor `Ismith2@gmail.com` should be `lsmith2@gmail.com` but never trust "Numerics", it can be costly when numbers don't add up to profit, or wrong medical dose is administered.

[image]

Once you have the text layout it's just the same processing as a searchable pdf so in this case its

```
xpdf-tools-win-4.03\bin64>pdftotext -layout -table a.pdf&type a.txt
                                          ALPHABETICAL                      LISTING                                        ABT

                                                                                     Place/Year                  of        Reg

      Name                              Addresss                                     Graduation                            Year

(John   Smith)                      AB                                               ABC   University    2001

                                                                                     BCC   University    2002              2000

Email:      jsmith@gmail.com            P:999-999-9999

                                                                                     DEF   University    2003

Jane    Smith                                                                        HGH   University/2001

                                    P:  111-111-111                                                                        2000

Email:      janes@gmail.com                                                          Some    Other       School      2002

                              201 FakeSt

Henry         Smith           Some        City,      Some  State  A1C  B23           University     ABC                    1999

                              P:111-2223333

                              301   Fake       St

Jason   Smith                 Some      City,      Some    State  A1C  B23           Univer         123                    2005

                              P:555-555-5555

                              401   Fake         St                                  ABC College                           2010

Luke   Smith                  Some      City,        Some  State  A1C  B23

Ismith2@gmail.com             P:   666-666-6666

                              501   Fake         St

                              Some      City,        Some  State  A1C  B23

                              P:666-666-6666

                              601   Fake       5St

                              Some      City,        Some  State  A1C  B23

                              P:   666-666-6666
```

and text import to a spreadsheet or other means you prefer should re-solve into cells, that need minimal tabular refitting.

Comment: @ KJ : thank you for your answer! if you have time, could you please provide some more information on how to "run tesseract as best it can from a shell command line via a pdf service (API) "? I am a complete noob at everything with "shell commands" and they somewhat intimidate me ... thank you so much !